# create folder based on package name in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm building a very simple java project and I need to do the following:

I don't need the packaged .jar file but the .class files along with the resources related to it, i.e. I have the following structure:

[image]

the idea is to be able to run a maven build and have the classes and the properties files all under a plugins folders as below:

[image]

This is because I need to copy the java classes and properties files with that structure to another app which consumes them. I want to automate the process of structuring the folders and just copy the plugins folder and paste it in the app that consumes it.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should learn to work the way Maven and many other tools do. Consuming a dependency is done by consuming jar files which will be placed on the classpath. This means you project should create a jar file and you can install it into your local cache via `mvn clean install` and in your other project you can simply define a dependency to it to consume it...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Maven AntRun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) to do simple file manipulations such as this (copying, moving files around) during the package phase.

A basic example would be this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <!-- create a directory -->
                     <mkdir dir="plugins"/>
                     <!-- copy files from one dir to another -->
                     <copy todir="put your target directory here">
                        <fileset dir="put your source directory here">
                            <exclude name="**/something/**"/>
                        </fileset>
                    </copy>
                 </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can use the `<tasks>` list to specify what should be copied (moved or deleted) and where as well as directories to create.

For example

```
<mkdir dir="target/plugins"/>
```

Could create the `target/plugins` directory, then you can copy files into it using:

```
<copy todir="put your target directory here">
    <fileset dir="put your source directory here">
        <exclude name="**/something/**"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Then by combining these rules you can reach the structure you want.